# How to fetch nested json array object using retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit

How to retrieve this ?
I tried creating 2 model class one for the "sys" and the other one is for the child of "sys" but it did not work:

class Sys:

```
public class Sys {
private ArrayList<SysInfo> sys = new ArrayList<>();

public ArrayList<SysInfo> getSys() {
    return sys;
}

public void setSys(ArrayList<SysInfo> sys) {
    this.sys = sys;
}
```

class SysInfo

```
public class SysInfo {
private String country;

public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}
```

And this is the JSON
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To get sys object user**

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class SysParent {
    @SerializedName("sys")

    private Sys sysObj;

    public Sys getSysObj() {
        return sysObj;
    }

    public void setSysObj(Sys sysObj) {
        this.sysObj = sysObj;
    }
}
```

**and to get values in sys use following class.**

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Sys {

    @SerializedName("country") private String country;

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
}
```